# Syntax Error: Multiline bash command in dockerfile RUN statement

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I have this Dockerfile, to which I am echoing the following line:

```
echo $"RUN cat file | while read pkg \
do\
  sudo apt-get install -qy $pkg \
done" >> Dockerfile
```

Now, when docker executes this line, I get the following error:

`/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
The command '/bin/sh -c cat autobuild/buildenv_packages | while read pkg do  sudo apt-get install -qy  done' returned a non-zero code: 1`

I know there is something small and syntactical I am missing, but I am unable to figure it out. Notice that the `$pkg` variable in the `apt-get install` statement isn't in the error.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslashes in your code only prevent the string from containing literal newlines; they are not written to the `Dockerfile`. Without a newline (or a semicolon) before `do`, the `while` condition never ends; you just have a giant list of arguments for the command `read`.

```
echo 'RUN while read pkg; do sudo apt-get install -qy "$pkg"; done < file' >> Dockerfile
```

Comment: Thanks ! That did it. I dont think I would have ever figured that out. Much appreciated :)